# Move complete tenant (structure + content) to another tenant in 0365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-migration

Is there a way where I can move complete site collections (site structure, enterprise metadata, content types, workflows, list & libraries with content) from one tenant to another tenant in 0365;

P.S. can't use site templates since I am using publishing infrastructure feature! is 3rd party tools the only way to go OR can we write a custom utility using SP Online `CSOM` & `REST API` to complete this task? Guidance needed!

Answer (score 2):

only option in your case is 3rd party tool, reason is you want to move everything( a complete site collection) and for that no OOTB method.

if you want just content then you can open both sites(source and destination) in explorer and copy paste the data. or save as template if no publishing feature.

I never tried this but you can ask O365 support, if they restore the site in destination tenant from the backup of source tenant.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use **Third party tools** like **Sharegate**, **MetaLogix** to migrate content within different tenants as there are many efficient tools available in the market. These tools will provide better functionalities than our custom code.